# Is there a way to have transparent video background in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a greenscreen HTML5 video and want to display it on a plane with a video texture using Three.js.

I tried to use two different video textures ( the video and the alpha channel ) but they are not perfectly synchronized in time and based on what I read it's very hard to sync two HTML5 videos.

I think using .webm video is the way to go but I can't manage to get the alpha channel working with Three.js.
Is it possible or is there another way to do it ? Thanks !

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: videoTexture, transparent: true } );
```

Comment: Not tested, but have a look at http://elevr.com/green-screening-video-on-the-web-a-threejs-extension/.

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley , I saw it earlier today but the result is not as good as working with a cleaned black & white texture

Comment: Related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/transparent-channel-on-video-texture/1200

Comment: @Mugen87 thanks, I saw it earlier too but setting "transparent: true" doesn't seems to be enough, and there's no real answer on the subject

Comment: Are you on Windows? What browser are you using?

Comment: @Mugen87 on a Mac using Chrome Safari & Firefox. Webm videos examples with transparency work, do you know if there's something more to do than just having a plane with a webm video texture ?

Comment: I've never worked with such videos so I can't tell you for sure. But I think this setup is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the format in order to have the transparency :

```
texture.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
```

Thanks everyone